# Receiving/sending data over sockets not completely working, only receiving the value once

Tags: c#, sockets

This is the the function for receiving the values from the client. But the problem is I'm receiving it only once. No matter how many time I send some data, the label on the MainWindows is being changed only once.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
private void HandleClientComm(object client)
{
    tcpClient = (TcpClient)client;
    NetworkStream clientStream = tcpClient.GetStream();

    byte[] message = new byte[4096];
    int bytesRead;

    while (true)
    {
        bytesRead = 0;

        try
        {
            bytesRead = clientStream.Read(message, 0, 4096);
        }
        catch
        {
            break;
        }

        if (bytesRead == 0)
        {
            break;
        }

        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(data))
        {
            ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();
            data = encoder.GetString(message, 0, bytesRead);

            MainWindow.Change(data);
            tcpClient.Close();
        }

        tcpClient.Close();

    }
```

On the client side I have this following example:

```
try
{
    TcpClient tcpclnt = new TcpClient();
    Console.WriteLine("Connecting.....");
    tcpclnt.Connect("127.0.0.1", 8001);
    Console.WriteLine("Connected");
    while (true)
    {
        Console.Write("Enter the string to be transmitted : ");
        String str = Console.ReadLine();
        Stream stm = tcpclnt.GetStream();
        ASCIIEncoding asen = new ASCIIEncoding();
        byte[] ba = asen.GetBytes(str);
        Console.WriteLine("Transmitting.....");
        stm.Write(ba, 0, ba.Length);
        stm.Flush();
        Console.WriteLine("Sent.....");
    }

    tcpclnt.Close();
    Console.Read();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error..... " + e.StackTrace);
}
```

Just a fast example, so when I enter the string name, the value changes the first time but when I enter a second time or if i exit the client program and reenter nothing changes, the value of the label content is equal to the first sent value.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like after the first successful read you are calling:

```
tcpClient.Close();
```

This will prevent any future reads from being successful.

If you would like avoid these sort of socket problems have you considered using the network library instead? I'm a developer for the library networkComms.net and you can find a short example  or what I mean [here](http://www.networkcomms.net/how-to-create-a-client-server-application-in-minutes/).

Comment: The link to your website isn't actually an answer to the question asked, and seems designed simply to advertise your library. Answers on Stack Overflow are expected to be *directly* related to the question that is being asked.

Comment: @AndrewBarber - IMHO the first part of my answer directly answers the the question. The second part makes the OP aware of what in my experience is a better solution. If I may not include the second part please advise.

Comment: I think with as often as you have been linking to your library, it has started to push the envelope where the Self-Promotion FAQ says you may be here 'for the wrong reasons'.

Answer (score 0):

You must use asynchronous server socket... see this sample from MSDN
[Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te.aspx)

Comment: @Antonio Please do not ask people to vote for or accept your answers.

Answer (score 0):

If you use clientStream.Read() after tcpClient.Close(), it will throw an exception, which will run your catch block and break you out of the loop.  (And you are calling tcpClient.Close() in *two* places *within* the loop so just getting rid of just one will not help.  Both of those are wrong.)

tcpClient.Close() should not be called unless you're completely done with the connection (moreover it should only be called once.)

Also,

"You must close the NetworkStream when you are through sending and receiving data. Closing TcpClient does not release the NetworkStream."

So make sure you close the TcpClient and the NetworkStream, but only when you're completely finished processing in the loop.